# Using POST in an HTML form

Tags: html, post, mason

I am using POST in an HTML form to POST large number of arguments.

I wrote something like this:

```
<form action="get_status_aisleid.html" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="aisleId" value=<% $aisle_id %> />
    <input type="hidden" name="enter code heretype" value="verified" />
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value=<% $values[1]%> />
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">
    <% $verifiedbaySize %>
    </a>
</form>
```

Everything works fine, if I click on a link in the same window.

But if I right click and open it in a new tab, then my new file (which is doing some operations on arguments passed and then downloading a file) is not called. Instead, the same page is refreshed.

Can someone please suggest something?

Comment: You cannot post to a HTML file. Period.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking an opening in a new window will always follow the link (i.e. `href="#"` meaning "Go to the top of the page". The JavaScript won't run.

No built in control of the browser will submit a form while giving the user the option to choose if it should be in the same or a new window.

This isn't normally a useful choice anyway - opening in a new window is something usually done when the user intends to return to the current page to pick up where they left off, and a form is not something normally presented in the middle of another task.

The closet you could come would be to add a second JavaScript triggered control that sets the `target` attribute of the form to `_blank` before triggering submission.